# past perfect progressive instead of past perfect simple?

Tags: past-perfect, past-perfect-continuous

This is from a novel:

The man who had sat next to her the day before began to laugh.

Is it possible to say: The man who had been sitting next to her the day before began to laugh?

Comment: Yes. Both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine and make sense. The meaning is also the same.